# Regex to extract string between 2 different characters and strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, pattern-matching

Short question, but can't make it work. I have a string:

```
COMPANY NAME - username (Name Surname).
```

What kind of regex will give me `username` (without spaces) from between `-` and `(` in such example?

It's ASP.NET C# if it makes any difference. Thanks in advance !

**EDIT :** 
The company name is a string with possible spaces. Username is without spaces. The characters  `-` and `(` are present only in these 2 places. I thought it was 100% obvious since I gave such example.

Comment: Can `username` ever contain spaces or parentheses?

Comment: Can the company name contain hyphens or parentheses?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the line will end in a fullstop?

Comment: Come on, more details. As the question is written now, the regex `username` meets your requirements...

Comment: @Tim-Pietzcker no spaces in username. Obviously I'd mention it if it was possible.

Comment: @Mark-Byers it's always 1 line from SQL database.

Comment: @yosh Then my regex should do the trick

Comment: @FailedDev: Your regular expression assumes that company names cannot contain hyphens and parentheses. xanatos' answer is better because it doesn't require this assumption.

Comment: @MarkByers As always it depends on how much complex you want your regex to be. Yes I agree that xanatos's answer is superior. That said, it is up to the OP to select the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var match = Regex.Match(
    "COMPANY - ltd (NAME) - username (Name Surname)", 
    @"^.* - (.*?) \(.*\)$"
);
var username = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

If your line ends with a `.` then the Regex is `@"^.* - (.*?) \(.*\)\.$"`

Through the use of `.*?` (the lazy quantifier) this Regex is quite resistant to strange "things" like the one I'm using as a test.

[Link](http://regexr.com?2uu3v) with tests. Pass over each row to see the capture group.

Answer (score 3):

```
string resultString = null;
try {
    resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString, @"-\s+(\S*)\s*\(").Groups[1].Value;
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Output : `username`

Comment: You can remove both `RegexOptions`. And of course this only works if `username` doesn't contain spaces. Which is a reasonable assumption, therefore +1.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Option were forgotten in from previous regex :S. +1 For pointing it out!

Comment: This is very good, thank you. Usually usernames don't contain spaces and I didn't mention spaces in question so assumption was good :)

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to test regexes with grep:

```
kent$  echo "COMPANY NAME - username (Name Surname)."|grep -Po '(?<=- ).*(?= \()'
username
```

Answer (score 0):

You can watch the below youtube regular expression video , i am sure the above question you can answer it yourself.

http://youtu.be/C2zm0roE-Uc